# How to include language files for each module in HMVC?

Tags: codeigniter

I am using CodeIgniter with HMVC and I would like to use language file for each module in addition to language files from CodeIgniter language folder.

Is this possible?

If yes, how could I do something like that?

E.g. I have a module called **footer**

with structure like this:

```
modules
   footer
       controllers
           footer.php
       language
           english
                footer.php 
           czech
                footer.php 
       models
           footer_model.php
       views
           footer.php
```

and this module would have a message in the view footer.php:

```
echo $this->lang->line('copyright_message');
```

Where key **copyright_message** will be stored in a file footer.php in a folder **language/english** for English and **language/czech** for Czech.

How to implement such thing in HMVC for CodeIgniter?

Comment: Did you check out http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/language.html ?

Comment: I am using HMVC, not classic MVC structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It actually works as in CI tutorial. My bad ;).